# How to stop parsing project when open Netbeans project

Tags: c, netbeans-8

I'm devoloping in a large project C language with Netbeans 8.2 IDE. First time I create project from source code, Netbeans parse project in a long time and it was succeed. But when I reopen this project, Netbeans reparse project, it make my computer slow, I can't do anything.
I have finded in google, there are some ways to fix it like disable reparse project but in version 8.2, I can't find that option.
Can you help me? Thank you very much!

Comment: What do you mean that your computer "overload"? What errors do you get (if any)? What problems do you have? What ***happens***?

Comment: I mean CPU and Ram cpu usage very high, about 95%. I can't do anything when Netbeans reparse my project.

Comment: Same thing here with NB 8.2. I have a big C project. C files are generated from another flavor of C code with another extension (.pc). I would like to have only the .pc files parsed and tried to setup NB this way. But it doesn't work and huge C files are analyzed, overloading my system as described by rum.